# How to return a simple query with aggregation using Spring Data Elasticsearch (latest version) and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to retrieve a list of aggregated brands using Spring-Boot 3 + Spring Data ElasticSearch 5 and Elasticsearch 8.

Currently, I am getting results but never aggregated ones.

I have gone through the documentation and searched on Google, but the answers I found, I tried to implement them without any conclusive results.

Here are my three approaches:

The basic query that works with Postman and returns the aggregated results:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brand",
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test 1, with StringQuery:

```
    Query query = new StringQuery("{" +
            "        \"match_all\" : {}" +
            "    }," +
            "    \"size\": 100," +
            "    \"aggs\": {" +
            "        \"distinct_brand\": {" +
            "            \"terms\": {" +
            "                \"field\": \"brand\"," +
            "                \"size\": 10000," +
            "                \"order\": {" +
            "                \"_key\": \"asc\"" +
            "        }" +
            "      }" +
            "    }" +
            "  }");

    SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);

    List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
            .map(SearchHit::getContent)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Test 2, with AggregationBuilders and withAggregation:

```
Aggregation aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms(ta -> ta.field("brand").size(10000));

Query query = NativeQuery.builder()
        .withQuery(q -> q.matchAll(ma -> ma))
        .withAggregation("distinct_brand", aggregation)
        .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000))
        .build();

SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);

List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
        .map(SearchHit::getContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Test 3, with JsonParser and SearchRequest:

```
JsonpMapper jsonpMapper = new JacksonJsonpMapper();
JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(new StringReader("{" +
        "        \"match_all\" : {}" +
        "    }," +
        "    \"size\": 100," +
        "    \"aggs\": {" +
        "        \"distinct_brand\": {" +
        "            \"terms\": {" +
        "                \"field\": \"brand\"," +
        "                \"size\": 10000," +
        "                \"order\": {" +
        "                \"_key\": \"asc\"" +
        "        }" +
        "      }" +
        "    }" +
        "  }"));

SearchRequest request = SearchRequest._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(jsonParser, jsonpMapper);

NativeQueryBuilder nativeQueryBuilder = NativeQuery.builder();

for (Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntry : request.aggregations().entrySet()) {
    nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation(aggregationEntry.getKey(), aggregationEntry.getValue());
}

Query query = nativeQueryBuilder.withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000)).build();
    SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);
    
List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
        .map(SearchHit::getContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test 1: You can only set the query string in a `StringQuery`, not aggregations, you need to use a `NativeQuery` for that

Test 2: That's the correct way to send the query, you should set the `maxResults` to 0 on the query, like you do in the direct API call. The reason you don't see the aggregation is because it is returned as a property of the returned `SearchHits` object, whereas your code collects the objects returned by the matchall query.

Comment: Could you show me how to return the aggregation?

Comment: you get them from Spring Data Elasticsearch in `SearchHits.getAggregations()`, what you do with that and you you return it to something that calls your code is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I got my aggregation this way:

```
Aggregation aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms(ta -> ta.field("brand").size(10000));

        Query query = NativeQuery.builder()
                .withMaxResults(0)
                .withQuery(q -> q.matchAll(ma -> ma))
                .withAggregation("distinct_brand", aggregation)
                .build();

        SearchHits<Vehicle> searchHits = searchOperations.search(query, Vehicle.class);

        ElasticsearchAggregations aggregations = (ElasticsearchAggregations) searchHits.getAggregations();
        List<ElasticsearchAggregation> aggregationsList = aggregations.aggregations();

        Buckets<StringTermsBucket> buckets = aggregationsList.get(0).aggregation().getAggregate().sterms().buckets();

        List<String> brandList = buckets.array().stream().map(bucket -> bucket.key().stringValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```